# Publicar Pagina Facebook SDK php

Tags: php, facebook

Como publicar numa página do facebook através do PHP?

estou tentando:

```
    require 'facebook_php_sdk/Facebook.php';

// ATENCAO, configurar os parametros abaixo
$APP_ID = "12345678"; // id da app
$SECRET = "***************************"; // secret da app
$PERMS = "publish_actions,manage_pages";

// objeto do facebook
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $APP_ID,
  'secret' => $SECRET,
));

// monta URL atual
$my_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// obtem CODE da autenticacao OAUTH
$code = $_REQUEST['code'];
if(empty($code)) {
        $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
               . $APP_ID . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
               . "&scope=$PERMS";

        header("Location: $dialog_url");
        exit;
}

// com o CODE vamos gerar a URL para obter o access token do usuario
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $APP_ID . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $SECRET . "&code=" . $code;

$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);

// printando o access token e quando ele ira expirar
echo "Access Token: ";
echo $params['access_token'];
echo "<br />";
if (!empty($params["expires"])) {
        echo "Ir&aacute; expirar em: " . date("d/m/Y H:i:s", time() + $params["expires"]);
}
```

Apenas recebo constantemente o erro:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/igosp794/public_html/modulo/administrativo/facebook_php_sdk/Facebook.php on line 24
```

Na linha 24 temos:

```
namespace Facebook
```

Comment: O que tem na linha **24 do arquivo /home/igosp794/public_html/modulo/administrativo/facebook_php_sdk/Facebook.php** ?

Comment: Apenas:  namespace Facebook;

Comment: Pode ser que a versão do php que você está usando não suporte o uso de namespace. Veja se a sua versão do php é superior a 5.3.

Comment: Opa amigão, perdoem-me a demora, atualizei o php do server, estou com o erro `Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in face.php on line 20`, linha 20 tem: `$facebook = new Facebook(array(`. No require_once seja com o  autoload.php ou Facebook.php, o erro é o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu pude perceber você não está usando o autoload do sdk do facebook. Mesmo resolvendo o erro descrito por você é pouco provável que funcione. O unico require_once que você deve fazer é o do arquivo autoload.php do sdk do facebook. Ele fará a inclusão automática das classes necessárias para o funcionamento da aplicação. Tudo isso supondo que você está usando a ultima versão do sdk.

Nesse [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted) você pode ver um tutorial de como fazer a correta instalação do sdk do facebook.